# Alfresco deployment doesn't work

Tags: maven, deployment, alfresco, activiti

I've created the simple example from [here](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html#hello-world-examples), then packaged it using mvn package, and made an effort to deploy the result amp file as described [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/amp-install.html). But after restarting Alfresco I didn't see any changes. There were no new variants of workflow to choose. The `java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar list <WARFileLocation>` executing showed that modules org.alfresco.integrations.google.docs and org.alfresco.vti are installed in the chosen war but not a word about my helloworld workflow

**UPD:** I looked deeper through the tutorial and found that to add an activiti to the share u first need to add some other activiti to the alfresco. it is told there:

> Open a command-line window and switch to
>   $TUTORIAL_HOME/workflow-tutorial-repo. Run mvn integration-test
>   -Pamp-to-war -Dmodule.log.level=debug. Your repo tier project will be installed and started on Tomcat running on port 8080. Open a new
>   command-line window and switch to
>   $TUTORIAL_HOME/workflow-tutorial-share. Run mvn integration-test
>   -Pamp-to-war -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081

why is it so? I can't just deploy the only one project to the share but need to make a progect for the Alfresco first?

Comment: try to build your amp file with this one. http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: @mitpatoliya, thank you, i tryed to do it in this way too but after `mvn integration-test -Pamp-to-war` command I can only access to http://localhost:8080/alfresco where I can't create any workflows and http://localhost:8080/share is not loading for I don't know what reason. after restart of cource I don't see any new workflows in the share interface

Comment: When share is not starting, it usually means there was some sort of error. You need to look into the console. Look for "workflow deployment failed" and "caused by". When you find the error code, it always helps to post this in your question here.

Answer (score 1):

By the command you wrote you start repo. Since share and repo running on the same server they should run on different ports, so for share you need to provide another port, which is done by additional parameter: -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081

**UPD**
@NikitinMikhail The quote you've added describes how to start **share**.
Alfresco consists of two projects (according to the maven sdk you use) which are repo and share.

> Alfresco Share provides a rich web-based collaboration environment for managing documents, wiki content, blogs and more. Share leverages the Alfresco repository to provide content services and utilises the Alfresco Surf Platform to provide the underlying presentation framework.

In other words share is just separate project which communicates with repo and provides better user interface than repo.

Comment: where it should be added? At the `mvn integration-test -Pamp-to-war` stage(I've just tryed to, it isn't possible)  or earliear or further?

Comment: oh, there is some information in http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html on how to create a progect for share where I have some problems with generated pom.xml but this is anither story

Comment: @NikitinMikhail Basically what I was trying to say is from this tutorial. First you need to create a share project and then run it: `cd yourProjName-share`
`mvn integration-test -Pamp-to-war -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081`

Comment: I did so but can't go further than login page as it says that log or pass is incorrect(that is wrong) or the Alfresco is unavailable